# Groovy: "def" keyword vs concrete type

Tags: groovy

Should we or should we not define the datatype of a variable or return type of a method if we know the datatype and also it is not going to change at runtime? What are the pros and cons or using def vs actual datatype?

One example being, if abc is intended to be `List<String>`

```
List<String> abc = "xyz"; //IntelliJ IDEA gives syntax highlighting for improper assignment
def abc = "xyz"; //IntelliJ IDEA will not give syntax highlighting
```

Comment: The official Groovy documentation has some suggestions on when to use which: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_optional_typing_advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicit typing in Groovy: sometimes or never?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262092/explicit-typing-in-groovy-sometimes-or-never)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's easy to fall into the trap of using `def` everywhere, due to convenience (especially if coming from Java)

But as you have seen, if you know the type of something, it's better to type it, especially on public methods. Benefits include; self documentation, ide hints, sanity...

Answer (score 16):

#### def ~= Object

As Tim pointed out, `def` is **not** a an alias to `Object` data type, but it can be though as one (`Object` is a class while `def` is just a Groovy keyword) - http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_variable_definition The only thing `def` has in common with `Object` is the fact that on the JVM level every `def` statement or type replacement is compiled to `Object`,

Consider very simple `test.groovy` script with following content:

```
def name = "John"

String surname = "Doe"

println "$name $surname"
```

If you compile it to `test.class` and take a look at the decompiled code here is what you will see:

```
Compiled from "test.groovy"
public class test extends groovy.lang.Script {
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;

  public test();
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          4       4     0  this   Ltest;

  public test(groovy.lang.Binding);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0       9     0  this   Ltest;
          0       9     1 context   Lgroovy/lang/Binding;

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      19     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;

  public java.lang.Object run();
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 4
      line 3: 9
      line 5: 14
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      63     0  this   Ltest;
          7      56     2  name   Ljava/lang/Object;
         12      51     3 surname   Ljava/lang/String;

  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
}
```

#### IDE syntax support

If you use IDE that supports Groovy well (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA) then you should be able to make usage of type inference and IDE would provide you a syntax support.

#### Purpose of `def` keyword

The main purpose of `def` is to introduce dynamic types in Groovy. As you can see in the above example, this is still old Java `Object` type.

The good practice is to use static types whenever you use static type on purpose. Your public API should definitely use static types for documentation reasons. I personally use `def` from time to time in two cases:

- in local variables that has very limited scope and variable name provides all information about the variable itself
- in Spock unit tests in test case name e.g. `def "should do something"() { }`