# Groovy documentation for passing an Integer argument to a BigDecimal parameter?

Tags: groovy

When I have a Java method that takes a BigDecimal parameter:

```
public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount)
```

then I can call it from Groovy using an integer argument like

```
m.setAmount(11)
```

Can anybody point me to Groovy documentation where this type coercion (?) is defined?

Extract from https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#_method_resolution

> An argument o of type A can be used for a parameter of type T if and only if:
>
> ...
>
> - or T and A derive from java.lang.Number and conform to the same rules as assignment of numbers

When I then look at the referenced rules for "assignment of numbers", there is no mention of T being BigDecimal:
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#number-assignment

In this question [Converting Integer to BigDecimal in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296049/converting-integer-to-bigdecimal-in-groovy) the answer gives a reference to Groovy's [BigDecimalCachedClasscoerceArgument(Object argument)](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/stdclasses/BigDecimalCachedClass.java#L38).
That method now even has a simpler implementation:

```
public Object coerceArgument(Object argument) {
    if (argument instanceof Number) {
       return NumberMath.toBigDecimal((Number) argument);
    }
    return argument;
}
```

So: Is the documentation just outdated?

Comment: The documentation is about method resolution under TypeChecked or CompileStatic operation isn't it, not type coercion?

Comment: @tim_yates Oh yes, on second look that section applies to TypeChecked I think (but not to CompileStatic). However, that still leaves the question open: Where is the type coercion to BigDecimal documented?