# Is the `def` keyword optional? If so, why use it?

Tags: groovy, syntax

I am aware that a variable can be dynamically typed with the `def` keyword in Groovy. But I have also noticed that in some circumstances it can be left out, such as when defining method parameters, eg `func(p1, p2)` instead of `func(def p1, def p2)`. The latter form is discouraged.

I have noticed that this is extendable to all code - anytime you want to define a variable and set its value, eg `var = 2` the `def` keyword can be safely left out. It only appears to be required if not instantiating the variable on creation, ie. `def var1` so that it can be instantiated as a `NullObject`.

Is this the only time `def` is useful? Can it be safely left out in all other declarations, for example, of classes and methods?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **you can't**. There are some use cases where skipping the type declaration (or `def` keyword) works, but it is not a general rule. For instance, Groovy scripts allow you to use variables without specific type declaration, e.g.

```
x = 10
```

However, it works because `groovy.lang.Script` class implements [`getProperty`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_2/src/main/java/groovy/lang/Script.java#L51-L57) and [`setProperty`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_2/src/main/java/groovy/lang/Script.java#L59-L66) methods that get triggered when you access a missing property. In this case, such a variable is promoted to be a global binding, not a local variable. If you try to do the same on any other class that does not implement those methods, you will end up getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`.

Skipping types in a method declaration is supported, both in dynamically compiled and statically compiled Groovy. But is it useful? It depends. In most cases, it's much better to declare the type for a better readability and documentation purpose. I would not recommend doing it in the public API - the user of your API will see `Object` type, while you may expect some specific type. It shows that this may work if your intention is to receive any object, no matter what is its specific type. (E.g. a method like `dump(obj)` could work like that.)

And last but not least, there is a way to skip type declaration in any context. You can use a `final` keyword for that.

```
class Foo {
    final id = 1

    void bar(final name) {
        final greet = "Hello, "

        println greet + name + "!"
    }
}
```

This way you can get a code that compiles with dynamic compilation, as well as with static compilation enabled. Of course, using `final` keyword prevents you from re-assigning the variable, but for the compiler, this is enough information to infer the proper type.

For more information, you can check a similar question that was asked on SO some time ago: [Groovy: "def" keyword vs concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825109/groovy-def-keyword-vs-concrete-type)

Answer (score 1):

in Groovy it plays an important role in **Global** and **Local** variable

if the variable name is same with and without def

def is considered **local** and without def its **global**

I have explained here in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994227/2986279

So if someone use with and without it will make a difference and can change things.